# Tree Collection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collections, treeview

When I make a list box in WPF I frequently set its ItemsSource to be a List.  Is there a Tree for TreeView (or what goes in ItemsSource for TreeView)?

Is there a collection or generally accepted method for handling tree data in C#.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is bind a collection of hierarchical objects to the tree view using the Hierarchical Data Template.

I have written a blog post on this very subject, check it out,

[Displaying Hierarchical Data with the WPF Tree View control](http://www.mattlong.com.au/?p=37)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Did you ever write the one about lazy loading?

Comment: Yep, planning to get to the lazy loading early next week, check back then.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Good Stuff!  Thanks for updating it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built in as far as I know. What I usually do is something like this:

```
class User  
{  
string Name { get; set; }  
List<User> { get; set; }  
}
```

Then you can use that to bind to your hierarchical control, such as a TreeView.

Comment: Actually, in WPF or Silverlight you probably want to use ObservableCollection instead of List. Then the UI will update automatically when you change your collection

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to data bind a source to a WPF `TreeView` instance.  Here are a couple of blogs and sample entries on the subject

- http://blogs.msdn.com/chkoenig/archive/2008/05/24/hierarchical-databinding-in-wpf.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972151.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project that was originally by [Wintellect](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerCollections.aspx), found here, called [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections). Maybe there is something there that might help you?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at binding XML via XLinq to your treeview, such as here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/02a47e46-12e9-45fb-af18-4511f2212acb/ and here: http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=50.